# Date keys displaying as integers in crossfilter.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data); 
var dateDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.datetime;});
var lessThan1K=dateDim.group().reduceCount();
print_filter("lessThan1K");
```

Print_filter prints the key, value pairs for my filter. However, unlike in other scripts I've written, where the key would be d.datetime, I get keys that are just long integers. The values are correct, the number of entries are correct, I'm just getting keys that I can't use. I can upload with all code and data, if my error is not apparent.

Comment: Looks ok. +d.datetime converts it to a numeric value, but it probably already was a numeric value? You'll probably have to share more code and explain what you'd expect to see instead.

Comment: `new Date(d.datetime)`  ?